# Tensorflow 2.x – Tensor with Average of Surrounding Cells

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'm trying to write a custom loss function in Tensorflow 2.x that encourages a gradual gradient in the output space (a 2D matrix). So, as one component of the loss function, I want to take in a Tensor and return a Tensor in which each cell represents the average of the corresponding neighbor cells in the original tensor.

[image: a harmonic matrix transformation]

For example, take the upper left cell: 6.3 = (7 + 9 + 3)/3. Or take the middle cell: 4.5 = (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2)/8.

Consider the following code:

```py
def gradient_encouraging_loss(y_true: Tensor, y_pred: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    gradient_loss: Tensor = tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(
        y_pred, tensor_harmonic(y_pred)
    ))), tf.cast(tf.size(y_pred), tf.float32))

    return gradient_loss
```

How would I implement `tensor_harmonic()`? `y_pred` has a shape of `(None, X, Y)`, where X and Y are the output matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a 2D convolution operation for the most part, but then you need to take extra care with the outer values. Here is how you could do it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def surround_average(x):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    dt = x.dtype
    # Compute surround sum
    filter = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]], dtype=dt)
    x2 = x[tf.newaxis, :, :, tf.newaxis]
    filter2 = filter[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]
    y2 = tf.nn.conv2d(x2, filter2, strides=1, padding='SAME')
    y = y2[0, :, :, 0]
    # Make matrix of number of surrounding elements
    s = tf.shape(x)
    d = tf.fill(s - 2, tf.constant(8, dtype=dt))
    d = tf.pad(d, [[0, 0], [1, 1]], constant_values=5)
    top_row = tf.concat([[3], tf.fill([s[1] - 2], tf.constant(5, dtype=dt)), [3]], axis=0)
    d = tf.concat([[top_row], d, [top_row]], axis=0)
    # Return average
    return y / d

# Test
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(24.), (4, 6))
print(x.numpy())
# [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
#  [ 6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11.]
#  [12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17.]
#  [18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23.]]
print(surround_average(x).numpy())
# [[ 4.6666665  4.6        5.6        6.6        7.6        8.333333 ]
#  [ 6.6        7.         8.         9.        10.        10.4      ]
#  [12.6       13.        14.        15.        16.        16.4      ]
#  [14.666667  15.4       16.4       17.4       18.4       18.333334 ]]
```

EDIT: The code above can be adapted to work with batches of matrices with a few minor changes:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def surround_average_batch(x):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    dt = x.dtype
    # Compute surround sum
    filter = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]], dtype=dt)
    x2 = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
    filter2 = filter[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]
    y2 = tf.nn.conv2d(x2, filter2, strides=1, padding='SAME')
    y = tf.squeeze(y2, axis=-1)
    # Make matrix of number of surrounding elements
    s = tf.shape(x)
    d = tf.fill(s[1:] - 2, tf.constant(8, dtype=dt))
    d = tf.pad(d, [[0, 0], [1, 1]], constant_values=5)
    top_row = tf.concat([[3], tf.fill([s[2] - 2], tf.constant(5, dtype=dt)), [3]], axis=0)
    d = tf.concat([[top_row], d, [top_row]], axis=0)
    # Return average
    return y / d

# Test
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(24.), (2, 4, 3))
print(x.numpy())
# [[[ 0.  1.  2.]
#   [ 3.  4.  5.]
#   [ 6.  7.  8.]
#   [ 9. 10. 11.]]
# 
#  [[12. 13. 14.]
#   [15. 16. 17.]
#   [18. 19. 20.]
#   [21. 22. 23.]]]
print(surround_average_batch(x).numpy())
# [[[ 2.6666667  2.8        3.3333333]
#   [ 3.6        4.         4.4      ]
#   [ 6.6        7.         7.4      ]
#   [ 7.6666665  8.2        8.333333 ]]
# 
#  [[14.666667  14.8       15.333333 ]
#   [15.6       16.        16.4      ]
#   [18.6       19.        19.4      ]
#   [19.666666  20.2       20.333334 ]]]
```

Comment: This does the trick for a 2D tensor! To make it work with a batch of 2D tensors of shape `(None, X, Y)`, I used `tf.map_fn(fn=surround_average, elems=y_pred)`, where `y_pred` was of the shape `(None, X, Y)`. Thank you!

Comment: @B.Freeman I added a batched version of the function, should be a lot faster than using `tf.map_fn`.